# Using rsync to recursively copy a directory while excluding a sub-directory but including a file in a sub-directory of the excluded sub-directory

Tags: rsync

I have a file tree that looks as such:

```
in
├── file1
├── dir1
└── dir2
    ├── dir3
    │   ├──── file2
    │   └──── junk1
    ├── junk2
    └── junk3
```

I want to create a sibling of `in` which looks like the following:

```
out
├── file1
├── dir1
└── dir2
    └─── dir3
         └── file2
```

In other words, recursively copy `in` to `out` excluding `in/dir2` but including `in/dir2/dir3/file2`.

I have tried the following:

```
rsync -a --exclude='in/dir2' --include='in/dir2/dir3/file2' in out
```

Which results in the following:

```
out
└── in
    └── file1
```

So I tried the following:

```
rsync -a --exclude='dir2' --include='dir2/dir3/file2' in/ out
```

Which results in:

```
out
└── file1
```

How can I achieve what I want with `rsync` or other unix tools? I would prefer to stay away from using weird methods like piping `tar` into `tar`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about breaking this up into more than one rsync command and bundle them into a shell script.

Another possible alternative is a combination of find with cpio to the destination device.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but I guess it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the `--exclude-from=FILE` and `--include-from=FILE` options with rsync.

```
--include-from=FILE
        This  option is related to the --include option, but it specifies a FILE that contains include patterns
        (one per line).  Blank lines in the file and lines starting with ’;’ or ’#’ are ignored.  If FILE is -,
        the list will be read from standard input.
```